# No overload for 'recognizer_SpeechRecognized' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple speech recognition application, but there is an error message in the below line. All code is compiling well, without any problem.

The error is in this line:

```
recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
```

and Below is the piece of code.

```
recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

        // initialize recognizer thread
        RecognizerState = true;
        RecThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RecThreadFunction));
        RecThread.Start();
    }
        public void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            // this event is raised when the speech recognizer recognizes speech.

            if (!RecognizerState)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                textBox1.Text = (" " + e.Result.Text.ToLower());
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an `EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>` but your method takes `SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs` as second parameter.So Event Handler and your method signatures doesn't match and that's why you are getting that error.Either change your method definition or the Event Handler.

Answer (score 0):

See the second argument of the event handler. You are using the event handler for `SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs`. You have to use `SpeechRecognizedEventArgs` instead of that. You can see sample code [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechrecognized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks to you also, you explained it well and problem is solved.